# Drupal - how to show images as slideshow in a "/node/*" page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, slideshow, drupal-theming

I have a content type which has fields as "Title", "Description", "Location" and "IMAGES".

When displaying the complete node content in URL like "www.mysite.com/node/14" where '14' is just an example node ID.... how do I display the IMAGES as a slideshow?

If I try to use Views module, and use the "slideshow" feature, I only get the slideshow with images. What I really want is -- for the page to show all fields in the content, i.e. "Title", "Description", "Location" and a SLIDESHOW of "IMAGES" at the end.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 lets you add field formatters to fields.  You can easily use this to add a slideshow field formatter so when the page renders your images they are in a slideshow.

Two modules that help with this are:

- [Flexslider](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider) module which says it, "Integrates with Fields (flexslider_fields)"
- [Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) which is specifically intended for this, but doesn't play nicely in responsive designs (in my experience)

You *could* also use Views for this by getting the current node ID in Contextual Filters and then using a relationship to get the images and **then** using Views Slideshow to render the resulting images in a block that is put on every node type...but as you can tell that is a roundabout way to achieve what a field formatter can probably do for you 90% of the time.

Comment: And one more module to help with this task: [Flexslider Gallery Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/flex_galleryformatter).

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

http://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider